# How Display All Post on a Category Page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Categories name 'Trending' and 'Top' I want to display all posts on both of these  Categories pages. I don't want to write custom query I want to edit **"global $wp_query;"** object and remove **"cat"** from the query to display all posts.

How it possible?

**My Code snap:**

```
    global $wp_query;
    if (isset($wp_query->query_vars[$monstrotheme->settings->slugs->frontendPosting->addNew])) {
        $this->data['specialPage'] = 'frontend-submit';
        $this->data['currentContentLayout'] = 'page';
    } else if ($wp_query->query_vars['pagename'] == $monstrotheme->settings->slugs->login->login) {
        $this->data['currentContentLayout'] = 'frontPage';
    } else {
        if (is_front_page() || is_404()) {
            $this->data['currentContentLayout'] = 'frontPage';
        } else if (is_post_type_archive('gallery') || is_tax('gallery-category') || is_tax('gallery-tag')) {
            $this->data['currentContentLayout'] = 'galleryArchive';
        } else if (is_post_type_archive('video') || is_tax('video-category') || is_tax('video-tag')) {
            $this->data['currentContentLayout'] = 'videoArchive';
        } else if (is_archive() || is_search() || (is_home() && !is_front_page())) {
            $this->data['currentContentLayout'] = 'postArchive';
            if (is_category('Trending')) {
                // Here I want to alter the query
            }
        } else if (is_page()) {
            $this->data['currentContentLayout'] = 'page';
        } else if (is_single()) {
            switch (get_post_type()) {
                case 'video':
                    $this->data['currentContentLayout'] = 'video';
                    break;
                case 'gallery':
                    $this->data['currentContentLayout'] = 'gallery';
                    break;
                default:
                    $this->data['currentContentLayout'] = 'post';
            }
        } else {
            exit;
        }
    }
```